# Optimized way of fetching ManyToMany fields in django model in single query

Tags: sql, django, performance, django-models

I have got following model structure in django.

```
Category:
    - name
    - description

Tag:
    - name

Article:
    - guid
    - title
    - detail
    - tags (Many2Many with Tag)
    - cats (Many2Many with Category)
```

Now in my bulk (upto 100,000) article update job I have to perform following actions.

```
- for each article:
     - to check if this article has already appeared in another category
         - if yes, associate article with current category
         - if no, create article along current category
     - to check if any of associated tags are exists or not,
          - if not exists create tag, and associate with current article
          - if exists, just associated with current article
```

While performing this operation I already have dictionary of existing articles which were fetched from the database.

Since ManyToMany fields dont have any effect on fetch operations like select_related() in django, is there any other way which can help me in loading existing articles along with categories and tags?

Answer (score 0):

If you add an [intermediary table](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/m2m_intermediary/) to the many-to-many-relations, eg `ArticleTag` you can query this table via django's ORM and use `select_related` on it:

```
# Get all 'tag-relations' WITH associated articles AND tags
articles_tags = ArticleTag.objects.all().select_related()
```

You could iterate then over the result an check if a specific article i associated with a tag... I guess there's no other way in django to query the table that represents the relation directly without specifying a `through`-model, otherwise you could still query it with using a raw sql query. If you have really much data this can maybe produce a lot ram usage, but nevertheless you will hit the database only once!